# Retry failed requests due to 401 Unauthorized after token refresh Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, unauthorized, retry-logic

I am currenlty using angular-oauth2-oidc for authentication I am facing an issue with retrying the failed requests after token refresh. i.e I when I make a request it fails due to an expired token then after token refresh how to retry the failed request. currenlty using this package for the reference. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc%60).

The below is my error interceptor which able to do refresh token

```
export function handl401ErrorInterceptor(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn) {
const oauthService = inject(OAuthService);
const handleServiceError = (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
if (error?.status === 401) {
   oauthService.refreshToken();
}
   return throwError(() => error);
};
   return next(request).pipe(catchError(error => handleServiceError(error)));
}
```